# How to get Popular Pages using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just implemented the new Facebook comments plugin. How can I easily get a list of the most popular pages on my site that have the most comments? I don't want to have to use the Graph API and query each page individually and look up the comment count for each page.

Comment: have you figured out a solution yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "bug" in the documentation that suggests it is not currently possible to find out what the top liked URLs in your domain are via FQL or the Graph API.  I don't believe this is the case, as FB claims that the API is more robust than the dashboard.

I have filed this bug report with FB:  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/192027544209678

I will update this answer once I either hack it on my own or FB updates their documentation.  This is definitely a burning question in the community.

Comment: any luck on this yet?

Comment: Negativo. It's been ignored by FB. Shocker. They are so good at documentation.~ :P

Comment: @Metagrapher still nothing? how about a recently shared page? any documentation on that? can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 2):

Look for graph insights or insights fql table. documentation is on facebook developer pages.

[edit]
Sorry, I misunderstood your question completely.
I doubt there is a solution available to your question. As far as I can see Facebook missed to add a method into the api to claim the top pages for a domain, even when they said in a blog post they will extend graph api ( http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/476/ )
All you can (currently) do with the graph api is to get stats for a specific url. To get a list of "top 10" you'ld need to crawl the api with all your urls, which is not practical.
If you just like to know (and not display on your page) the current "top" lists, then look into your facebook insights ( http://www.facebook.com/insights ) - select your domain, "Comment Box" - then there should be a "Popular pages" submenu. Same for "Likes" and "Sends".

Comment: That's really very vague and not so helpful.  You may as well have put:
tldr;:RTFM

Comment: Thanks for the edit. :) That seems to be the proper answer.  As well, you can watch this here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/192027544209678

Comment: Aehm, yes... this bug entry on the new bug tracker of FB I just liked to add too ;)

Comment: Yes, please! Do go follow and 'like' the bug! The more that 'like'/follow it, the more likely they are to take it seriously :)  Thank you!!